# how to query from a list in a document where 2 criteria must be true together

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have the followings 3 dummy documents. I wish to find all documents where the end_terminal is "LGA" **AND the value is equal or above 0.50** for the same end_terminal.

for this I do:

```
db.getCollection('test_coll').aggregate(
[
    {'$match': {'$and':
                        [
                            {'return_options.end_terminal':'LGA'},
                            {'return_options.value':{'$gte':0.5}}
                        ]
        
                }
     }
]

)
```

but the results are the first 2 documents (I take it the query looks at ANY document >= 0.5)

```
/* 1 */
{
"_id" : ObjectId("60a2c0621e5f043b735e36ef"),
"car_id" : 1900641778,
"terminal" : "JFK",
"return_options" : [ 
    {
        "end_terminal" : "LGA",
        "value" : 0.81
    }, 
    {
        "end_terminal" : "YYZ",
        "value" : 0.15
    }, 
    {
        "end_terminal" : "MIA",
        "value" : 0.04
    }
]
}

/* 2 */
{
"_id" : ObjectId("60a7ce2c3df71a85997cc248"),
"car_id" : 1900641779,
"terminal" : "YYZ",
"return_options" : [ 
    {
        "end_terminal" : "JFK",
        "value" : 0.5
    }, 
    {
        "end_terminal" : "ORD",
        "value" : 0.1
    }, 
    {
        "end_terminal" : "LGA",
        "value" : 0.4
    }
]
}

 /* 3 */
{
"_id" : ObjectId("60a7cf1b3df71a85997cc3f8"),
"car_id" : 1900641778,
"terminal" : "ORD",
"return_options" : [ 
    {
        "end_terminal" : "EWR",
        "value" : 0.71
    }, 
    {
        "end_terminal" : "YYZ",
        "value" : 0.25
    }, 
    {
        "end_terminal" : "LAS",
        "value" : 0.04
    }
]
}
```

[image]

Also- how to project the results of only the item from the return_options. In other words, do not project any item from the list `return_options` if doesnt meet the query criteria (dont care about YYZ, MIA) only LGA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$filter`

- If you need to exclude the documents which don't meet any condition, you can use `$match`. Otherwise you can only use `$project`

Here is the code

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "return_options.end_terminal": "LGA",
      "return_options.value": { $gte: 0.5 }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      return_options: {
        "$filter": {
          "input": "$return_options",
          "cond": {
            "$and": [
              { $eq: [ "$$this.end_terminal", "LGA" ] },
              { "$gte": [ "$$this.value", 0.5 ] }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      $expr: { $ne: [ "$return_options", [] ] }
    }
  }
])
```

**Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/1A6GhcgwGsT)**

Comment: Perfect! thank you. one followup question: say there's another field in the return_option (call it route. so you have end_terminal, value and route) and you dont want to project this field. How would you go around it? thanks again

Comment: You can use `$project` like https://mongoplayground.net/p/3HMkWcT1xlp

Comment: from now on you're King Varman. Much appreciated!

Comment: haha not like tht, @ProcolHarum try to answer SO mongodb questions, you will get the knowledge as soon